# groups['hogehoge'] と書いてある ansible の変数はどこで設定される？

Tags: ansible

Ansible のソースコードを見ている中で、次のような記述を見かけました。
vars.yml (変数定義の yaml ファイル)の中での記述です。

```
SOME_VAR: "{{ groups['hogehoge'][0] }}"
```

この `groups` 変数(のようなもの)はどのように定義されますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これは、 inventory で定義される group を参照するための構文です。
例えば、 inventory の中で次のような記述があった場合、 上記の変数参照は `11.22.33.44` に置換されます。

```
[hogehoge]
11.22.33.44
11.22.33.45
```